# Find a sub-node from a node by xpath

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to go through some fields and print out the texts. However, I can't find a function that can output a sub-node given a node and the xpath to that sub-node.

In the following code snippet, I used the non-existing function "getSubnode".  Would appreciate if someone could give me a hint on how to implement it.

```
x = $('div.content');
for (i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
    y1 = getSubnode(x[i], "span/strong");
    y2 = getSubnode(x[i], "a/strong");
    console.log(y1.textContent, y2.textContent)
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: that function would return an array not a single node

Comment: @guido, that makes sense.  Do you have an example on how to implement something similar to getSubnode() and returns a list of nodes?

Comment: it is not clear to me what you want to do, however the xpath for the nodes you want to select would be `//div[@class='content']//span/strong|//div[@class='content']//a/strong`

Comment: @guido sorry, didn't state my question clear enough.  I need to do XPath starting from node, not from the root.